# Trying to remember a book about fantasy and amnesia

Tags: story-identification, novel

The main character is a girl whose family dies and moves in with her aunt. There she meets a boy that she feels like she knows but doesn't remember. Basically these people are offered the chance to remember their past lives after they're reborn, and for some reason she chooses not to. I remember it was a saga but I don't really remember the name and I would like to reread it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Please have a look over the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/31394) and see if you can think of any more details to add to your question. When did you read it? How old was it? What language was it written in? Where was it set? Also, what do you mean by a saga?

Comment: You've forgotten a book about amnesia?